# What is the most elegant way to write an if condition with multiple OR operators?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I am checking if a variable matches with any of the following strings:

```
if (re == "Neliöhinta"||re == "Yhtiövastike"||re == "Vesimaksu"||re == "Hoitovastike"||re == "Rahoitusvastike") {
  //do something
}
```

I was wondering, is there a more elegant/shorter way to write this if condition? Something along the lines of

```
if(re == ("Neliöhinta"||"Yhtiövastike"||"Vesimaksu"||"Hoitovastike"||"Rahoitusvastike"))
```

(which doesn't work)

Best I have found so far is

```
if(/Neliöhinta|Yhtiövastike|Vesimaksu|Hoitovastike|Rahoitusvastike/g.test(field))
```

Any other ways to do this?
Cheers

Comment: For a long list, `Array#includes` is the modern way (or `Array#some` if the elements are non primitives). `Array#findIndex` would be commonly used in ES5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array instead:

```
const permittedWords = ["Neliöhinta", "Yhtiövastike", "Vesimaksu", "Hoitovastike", "Rahoitusvastike"];
if (permittedWords.includes(re)) {
  // do something
}
```

Your current technique won't work perfectly, because it'll also match strings which *include* the word but don't exactly match it, eg `aaaaNeliöhinta`. To fix the regular expression, anchor it to the beginning and end of the string with `^` and `$`, and remove the global flag:

```
if(/^(?:Neliöhinta|Yhtiövastike|Vesimaksu|Hoitovastike|Rahoitusvastike)$/.test(field))
```